# How make a subtitle box inside a title box

Tags: html, css, frontend

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeI7U.png

I'm having some problems in completing the design of this box.

I already did the circular box with the image inside
i already did the rectangle title box

Now I need make the second box.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/jhhw579k/1/

HTML:

```
<section class="about">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <figure class="circle-image-box-with-caption">
            <img class="wow rotateIn" src="ilorempixel.com/250/250/sports/"/>
            <figcaption>
                <h2>SOMETHING HERE</h2>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
 .col-md-4 {
    padding: 50px;
}
 .circle-image-box-with-caption {
    position: relative;
}
 .circle-image-box-with-caption img {
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
    width: 254px;
    height: 254px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #f98835; 
}
 .circle-image-box-with-caption figcaption {
    max-width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 20px;
    bottom: -40px;
    border: 1px solid #f98835;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    background: #f98835;
}
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Dr8IEQm.png That's what I've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used absolute positioning, and positioned it at the bottom right using right and bottom properties. you can play with the 2% space and padding I used. You probably dont need such high z-index as well and can change the color

http://jsfiddle.net/jpwjt300/

```
.subtitle {
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:99999;
    right: 2%;
    bottom: 2%;
    padding: 2%;
}
```